# Trouble forming the classes and methods for object orientated python project

Tags: python, class, object

I am working on project but am struggling to properly use classes and object orientation without cutting corners.

I will now post the project to clear up my needs:

> A student object consists of:
>
> ```
> FirstName: string
> LastName: string
> Birthdate: tuple, such as (1,17,1998)
> TechID: string
> Grades: list of tuples, such as [(3127,”C”,4),(2496,”B”,3),(6703,”D”,3)]
>  So one student might look like this:
>
> FirstName: “Bob”
> LastName: “Smith”
> Birthdate: (2,17,1998)
> TechID: “43546578”
> Grades: [(5930,”B”,4),(7660,”C”,4),(3122,”C”,3),(5438,”C”,2),
>    (6730,”C”,4),(4268,”C”,4),(5709,”D”,4),(8071,”B”,4)]
> ```
>
> The data for each student can be found in the text files. Your program
>   should read the data from each of the files, as appropriate. (Do not
>   change the format of the input files.) Your getData function should
>   read in *all* of the data, at one time. And once all of the data has
>   been read into an appropriate structure, that data should be passed
>   back to the main program. Your program should not go back-and-forth
>   between reading data and returning data.
>
> Create a list of students. Do not process the students one-by-one as
>   they are created or as they are placed in the list. Create a student,
>   add it to the list of student objects, repeat. Once the list of
>   students is complete, go through the list to output the report on each
>   student.
>
> You will need three methods for processing a student object.
>
> 1. currentAge: How old is the student?
> 2. currentGPA: What is the student’s GPA?
> 3. Report: Add the output for that student to the output file.
>
> Each output file item should look like this:
>
> ```
> Bob Smith (#43546578)
> Age:  18 (02/17/1998)   note the mm/dd/yyyy format
> GPA: 2.14 (29 credits)
> ```
>
> There will be at least three Python files. one for getData, one with
>   the student class and its methods, and one with the main program.
>
> The student.txt looks like this:
>
> ```
> 87965164,Paris,Yu,6/27/1997
> 87965219,Heath,Moss,10/13/1996
> 87965187,Cale,Blankenship,10/22/1995
> 87965220,Terrence,Watkins,12/7/1996
> 87965172,Ansley,Padilla,3/30/1997
> ```
>
> And the grades.txt looks like this:
>
> ```
> 87965220,2915D3
> 87965219,7252C3
> 87965164,6964D3
> 87965219,5569A4
> 87965220,8923C4
> 87965187,2818A4
> 87965187,5293C3
> 87965187,5753C3
> 87965172,8581B3
> 87965219,3904B4
> 87965220,5801D3
> 87965219,3418A3
> 87965219,3544C4
> 87965220,7626A4
> 87965187,5092D3
> 87965187,3312C4
> 87965164,8119C4
> ```

Here is my code. my problem is that i have come to realize i am not utilizing Classes and objects well. I am looking for some kind of guidance or examples of how i should go about this project. If someone were able to help create a template for what classes and methods should exist that would be fantastic.

```
import re

class GetData:
    fullList = []
    birthdays = []
    students = []

    def studentsInFile(self):
        count = 0            
        inputStudents = open('students.txt' , 'r')
        for line in inputStudents:
            self.fullList.append(re.split('[,/]',line.strip()))

        inputStudents.close()            
        numOfStudents = len(self.fullList)

        while count != numOfStudents:
            self.students.append(self.fullList[count][0])
            self.birthdays.append(self.fullList[count][3:6])
            self.birthdays[count][:] = [int(x) for x in self.birthdays[count]]
            count += 1

    def gradesInFile(self):
        inputGrades = open('grades.txt' , 'r')                  
        inputGrades.close()

getData = GetData()
getData.studentsInFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you have done your abstraction in a completely wrong way.

Firstly I should probably tell you what is OOP and why you should/shouldn't use it. Shortly speaking **Object Oriented Programming** (OOP) is a programming [paradigm](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~bernardy/pp/Lectures.html#sec-1), which simply speaking is based on the concept of objects. An object is something that you could imagine inside your head like an object. And so a Car is an object, a Dog is an object, a *Student* is an object and so on. And Classes are prototypes of these objects.

Now, objects may contain **data** which is used to describe them and methods/functions/procedures which allow them to interact with a program (or in our little abstraction - with the World). So for example you could have a brown dog, which is able to woof or stare into you for endless hours until you give him what he wants (food and back scratching obviously). More difficult example might be a Car, which might interact with the Engine object and Wheel objects etc. Everything depends on how deep you want to go with your abstraction details, because you could simply create a Car object, which has the ability to turn wheels, start an engine, accelerate and its wheels position, engine state and speed might be represented as data (variables or class properties, which are two different things in Python). Everything depends on what you want and what you need.

In your example you've tried to represent `GetData` as an Object, and so you have written the class prototype and created an object. I've tried incredibly hard, but I simply couldn't imagine `GetData` as an Object, so even if it is possible it is probably example of wrong class design.

Much better solution would be to build a `Student` class, which might containt data fields, which you mentioned at the beginning of your post and methods like `setDateFromText`, which would set `Student.age` from `string` provided as argument - for example `02/17/1998`, which you gave as an example in your post and store the text birthdate in seperate variable.

Also you do not need regular expressions in this example. `split` method of builtin `str` class is more than enough.